# Why is the element of a list of data.frames still a list element and no data.frame?

Tags: r, csv, apply

I want to read the CSVs from a folder, subset over all of them and return the subset. However, I have my problems with the apply functions, since I can't access the data the way I want. What would be a good way to do this and what am I not getting here?

```
#specifiy files in folder with relative path: "data/1.csv" etc.
selected.files <- dir(path = "data", pattern = "*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

#returns list of same length as selected.files, each elemt is a data.frame corresponding to read.csv("1.csv")
selected.frame <- lapply(selected.files, read.csv)

#returns list
class(selected.frame[1])`
```

Now, I'm not sure how to proceed. I would have expected that I can use an apply function again to access an element of the selected.frame list, treat it as a data.frame and use the subset function on it.

Comment: Use double brackets to get the item, single brackets leave it as a list. (`class(selected.frame[[1]])`)

Comment: Ok, so how can I access the data.frames within an apply function then, say sapply and subset them further?

Comment: We probably need to see a few elements of `selected.files` and their respective results to answer confidently.

Comment: Hm, I'm not entirely sure what you want. If the datasets have similar structures you could create a single dataset (If they have the same columns, but different rows `do.call(rbind, selected.frame)` or if they have different columns but the same row you could `cbind` or `merge` them on some id variable). Otherwise you'll have to keep them in a list with functions like `lapply()` such as `lapply(selected.frames, function(x) x[1,])` to get the first row of each.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is just the subset of the element. Even though it has just one item it is still a list or a data.frame.

Comment: x <- subset(selected.frame[[1]], select = c(col1, col2))
y <- sapply(x, mean, na.rm=TRUE) Ok, I could build a subset like that. How would I do it for multiple data.frames of selected.frame and isn't there a much nicer way to do this in general?